# Существует ли проверка на поддержку браузером клиента определенных технологий?

Tags: веб-программирование, технологии

К примеру сайт полностью по последнему слову на grid или flex, но стандартный броузер android и многие броузеры под linux и понятие не имеют о flexbox и тем более о grid .

Существует ли некая проверка которая подсунет user ту версию которая поддерживается его устройством ?

Если даже учесть что у меня есть какая то asha которая float не понимает .. видит только table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По логике, это можно узнать со стороны клиента, скажем, средствами javascript. Однако в 2013 году Firefox, Chrome и Opera «объявили» о поддержке специальной директивы под названием @supports и её JavaScript аналога — функции CSS.supports().

```
@supports (property: value) { /* Стили */ }
```

Пример использования 
`@supports (display: flex) { /* Стили */ }
@supports not (display: flex) { /* Стили */ }
@supports (display: flex) or (display: -webkit-flex) { /* Стили */ }`

Подробнее [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/336466/)